# Is there a way to access the children of a CategoryChannel before it is deleted? [Discord.js]

Tags: discord, discord.js

I handle a channelDelete event in my discord bot.
My original intent was to do the following:

1. Listen for when a channel is deleted
2. Check to see if its type equals 'GUILD_CATEGORY'
3. Delete all the channels under that category

I can typically access channels under a `CategoryChannel` through its property called `children` anywhere else except during this event...

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'channelDelete',
    once: false,
    async execute(channel) {
        if(channel.type == 'GUILD_CATEGORY')
            for(let [child_id, child] of channel.children)
                if (child.deletable) child.delete();
    },
}
```

I can confirm the code is being executed, but the problem is that the incoming channel object is in a state where it is already deleted, and I cannot get the children:

- During debugging, I noticed the channel object has the property `deleted: true`
- The `children` property is empty, even though I know there were channels in that channel category prior to deletion

Is there a way for my bot to collect and handle the children of a `CategoryChannel` prior to its deletion?

Comment: Perhaps, try adding the Guild parameter here `async execute(channel, guild) {` and perform a fetch where you search for the channel (category) `await guild.channels.fetch(channel);`. According to [BaseFetchOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/typedef/BaseFetchOptions), by not specifying if you want it to be saved in the cache it is saved automatically, that could help you (All this obviously before the for loop runs).

Comment: @Teyrox Hi Teyrox. Thanks for the tip. It was a good idea, and I was able to get the cached channels, however, any association the channels had with the category seems to be lost. I am worried that this is expected behavior, and I would have to find another strategy of persisting the association before a CATEGORY_CHANNEL is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why?

Unfortunately, this is how CategoryChannels work in discord.js...
When the category is deleted, discord.js sends a request to the API to delete the channel. Only then, Discord sends you the event after the category is deleted.
What happens next is that the children are not located in the category anymore! So you will not be able to get the children inside the CategoryChannel object.

---

This is the code for the `children` property

```js
get children() {
    return this.guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.parentId === this.id);
}
```

It filters the channels which are in the guild, but those children channels are not located in the category anymore. Which is the reason the property is empty.

## The (Only?) Solution

This will require caching the channels themselves. As there aren't really any other solutions.
You may cache the channels in different ways.
**Just remember...** there are instances and references in Javascript, and failure to acknowledge may lead to weird behaviors. The following code only works for small bots without sharding, just so you know.

```js
const cachedChannels = new Map()

client.on('ready', () => {
  // Looping thru guilds...
  client.guilds.forEach((guild) => {
    // Filtering the channels to category channels only and looping thru them...
    guild.channels.filter((channel) => channel.type === "GUILD_CATEGORY").forEach((category) => {
      // Note on references and instances: Numbers, Strings and Booleans do not have instances like Object, Arrays, etc. do
      // We are using an array here to abuse the references
      cachedChannels.set(category.id, [])

      // Looping thru the children channels...
      category.children.forEach((children) => {
        // This is the array we've created earlier
        const storedChannels = cachedChannels.get(category.id)

        // Pushing the ID so we can fetch them later
        storedChannels.push(children.id)
      })
    })
  })
})

client.on('channelDelete', (channel) => {
  if (channel.type === "GUILD_CATEGORY") {
    // Looping thru our cached channel IDs defined earlier
    cachedChannels.get(channel.id).forEach((id) => {
      const child = channel.guild.channels.get(id)
      child.delete()
    })

    // Delete the cached IDs to save memory
    cachedChannels.delete(channel.id)
  }
})
```

Comment: I was afraid that this might be the only way, but it is a viable solution to this problem. My bot is small in particular and is designed to work on only one guild, so it works out pretty well. Thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

### You can use the channelUpdate event.

---

According to the discord docs, [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#deleteclose-channel), when the category is deleted, the `channelUpdate` event is fired for all the children. You will still have to cache it temporarily, as there doesn't seem to be a way to detect if the category was deleted in the `channelUpdate` event, but you won't need to cache all channels.